# Need To Know the Syntax of Filter in OData query Message Trace API

Tags: http, outlook, office365, odata, exchangewebservices

URL

```
https://reports.office365.com/ecp/reportingwebservice/reporting.svc/MessageTrace?$filter=StartDate ge DateTime'2023-07-14T00:00:00Z' and EndDate le datetime'2023-07-14T23:59:59Z'
```

Error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
    <m:code>UnknownError</m:code>
    <m:message xml:lang="">An error has occurred on the server.</m:message>
</m:error>
```

Try to Add Filter for DateTime(Start Date and End Date) but it return Error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `eq` operator instead of `ge` and `le`.

```
https://reports.office365.com/ecp/reportingwebservice/reporting.svc/MessageTrace?$filter=StartDate eq datetime'2023-07-14T00:00:00Z' and EndDate eq datetime'2023-07-14T23:59:59Z'
```